# How to import a datatable (.txt) to Amchart with two different delimiters between the columns?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, leaflet, amcharts4

I want to import the data from myfile.txt file under amchart in order to make figures later.

Nevertheless, the columns of my table are separated by two delimiters. The delimiter between the first and the second column is the comma, then for the rest of the columns it is the space.

I used in the code below the command "delimiter" twice (once to define the commas and another time to define the spaces) but without giving results.

Can you please correct my code below !

Thank you in advance

data of myfile.txt:

```
8.258,201906302058  2.103   0.002   25.822
2.693,201906302108  2.102   0.001   25.802
7.245,201906302118  2.106   0.002   26.154
3.83,201906302128   2.085   0.001   26.08
6.028,201906302138  2.088   0.004   26.183
7.313,201906302148  2.105   0.003   26.176
5.259,201906302158  2.098   0.002   26.331
4.876,201906302208  2.1 0.002   26.357
8.447,201906302218  2.077   0.003   26.291
9.091,201906302228  2.072   0.004   26.267
12.176,201906302238 2.068   0.004   26.17
5.186,201906302248  2.057   0.003   26.206
3.069,201906302258  2.037   0.001   26.176
2.958,201906302308  2.023   0.002   25.96
7.234,201906302318  2.044   0.003   25.9
3.706,201906302328  2.036   0.002   25.869
10.287,201906302338 2.041   0.005   25.954
5.614,201906302348  2.04    0.003   26.007
```

The second column is the date !

Here is my code :

```
 // Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);


// Set up data source

chart.dataSource.url = "https://..../amchart/myfile.txt";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.CSVParser();

chart.dataSource.parser.option.delimiter = ",";
chart.dataSource.parser.option.delimiter = "\t";

chart.dataSource.parser.options.useColumnNames = false;


// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "col1";

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "col2";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "col1";
series1.name = "P";
series1.strokeWidth = 1;
series1.tensionX = 0.7;
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "col3";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "col1";
series2.name = "T";
series2.strokeWidth = 1;
series2.tensionX = 0.7;
series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "col4";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "col1";
series3.name = "V";
series3.strokeWidth = 1;
series3.tensionX = 0.7;
series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());

 // Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do some pre-processing of the data file and change the commas to tabs. In powershell this would look like this

```
(Get-Content -path data.txt -Raw) -replace ",","`t" > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how to put this command line in amchart?

Thank you again for your help. I'm really new to JS programming

Comment: This is windows powershell command. This is modifying the data file outside of the web app. How is the data file created? Do you have control over this?

Comment: In fact, I have a field instrument that regularly sends data to a server. These data are stored in a table (.txt) as in the example I gave above (myfile.txt). In fact, my goal is to display my data in live? The data in my table is updated regularly. That's why I want to integrate a pre-processing command into my amchart code

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?